# Sas table empties itself

Tags: database, model, sas, statistics, regression

So I'm doing an exercise in SAS which is supposed to teach us to create multiple tests for heteroscedasticity.
I do my tests and then I have to keep the residual of a test in order to correct variables.

But the d table always ends up with 0 observations, it's almost as if it empties itself since I stated it was based on the original dataset. I spent 3h on it, I can't figured out why it would do that. I has happened multiple times on several machines.

here is my code:

```
libname mag "/folders/myfolders/data/";

data c; set mag.drogue;
lg_pxogramme= log(pxogramme);
lg_qtitegramme= log(qtitegramme);
run;
data d; set c;
run;

/*2. App Brandt*/
proc contents data=c;
proc reg data=c;
model lg_pxogramme= lg_qtitegramme puretemoy /spec;
output out=d r=r_hat;
run;

/*3.*/
data d;
lg_pxogramme= log(pxogramme);
lg_qtitegramme= log(qtitegramme);
r_2= r_hat**2;
run;
proc reg data=d;
model r_2= lg_qtitegramme puretemoy;
output out=d p=p_hat;
run;
data d;
pxogramme_c= lg_pxogramme/p_hat;
qtitegramme_c= lg_qtitegramme/p_hat;
puretemoy_c= puretemoy/p_hat;
run;
proc reg data=d;
model pxogramme_c= qtitegramme_c puretemoy_c;
run;
```

The two errors I got were:

- ERROR: Variable PURETEMOY not found.
- ERROR: No valid observations are found.

Probably because the table was empty since it comes after the data step, the two errors show up when I specify the model.

Comment: As you create table `d` from scratch at the end of your code, if there is an error that prevents SAS from executing the data step, the output table is empty. Check out why column `PURETEMOY` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recreating the d data set with statements like this:

```
data d;
lg_pxogramme= log(pxogramme);
lg_qtitegramme= log(qtitegramme);
r_2= r_hat**2;
run;
```

If you are trying to include the old copy, you need to add a `set` statement:

```
data d;
set d;
lg_pxogramme= log(pxogramme);
lg_qtitegramme= log(qtitegramme);
r_2= r_hat**2;
run;
```

Comment: I put my outputs in another table (call it e) I merged with d by using "set d e"
Worked perfectly eventhough I couldn't find the values of the outputs in d after the program was executed. Weird but ok I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In your first step, you create a dataset called `c` and then a copy of it called `d`.
In your second step, you "erase" dataset `d` replace it by the output of the `proc reg` on dataset `d` by specifying `out=d` on the `proc reg` statement.

In your third step, all you do is overwriting `d` again in every `data` and `proc` steps. In your `data d;` steps, you create a new dataset each time from nothing (no `set` statement) which contains just one record of missing values since you assign values from variables that do not exist. In your `proc reg` steps, your read from `d` (`data=d`) and output to `d` (`out=d`) essantially overwriting your data with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Double check what you have asked SAS to do and read the SAS log to see what it has done. For each step it will show what data it read and what data it wrote.

Let's look at some of the program steps.

First it reads in an existing dataset and creates `C`. Creating a couple of new variables as it does this.

```
data c;
  set mag.drogue;
  lg_pxogramme= log(pxogramme);
  lg_qtitegramme= log(qtitegramme);
run;
```

Then it duplicates this new dataset into `D`.

```
data d;
  set c;
run;
```

And then the code overwrites `D` with the results of the regression analysis. See the `OUT=D` on the `OUTPUT` statement?

```
proc reg data=c;
  model lg_pxogramme= lg_qtitegramme puretemoy /spec;
  output out=d r=r_hat;
run;
```

After that it again overwrites `D` using a data step that has no input data. So it creates `D` with one observation and 6 missing variables.

```
data d;
  lg_pxogramme= log(pxogramme);
  lg_qtitegramme= log(qtitegramme);
  r_2= r_hat**2;
run;
```

First fix this step. You need to add a `SET` statement to tell it what data to read. You should also use a different output dataset to prevent overwriting the output of your regression.  Do you want it to read the output of the regression?  The `C` dataset the first step created? The original permanent dataset that was used to create `C`?